# Cannot get on refresh angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, route-provider, angularjs-ng-route

All my route in app.js working fine, on refreshing page.

I have to create a route with special params like this :

http://localhost:9000/bureaux-a-louer/rhone/lyon/69003/filters?lat=45.7593054&lng=4.841594600000008

From the homepage to this route it works well , i can get all parameters. But when i refresh this i got

**Cannot get** /bureaux-a-louer/rhone/lyon/69003/filters?lat=45.7593054&lng=4.841594600000008

Looks like the dot parameters breaks it... because when i put a comma in lat/lng parameters it's working fine... 
If someone have an idea to fix it.

It's an Angular application on 1.5.7 , with ng route param like this :

```
.when('/bureaux-a-louer/:cp/:city/:zipcode/:filters', {
            templateUrl: 'views/search/search.html',
            controller: 'SearchCtrl',
            controllerAs: 'search',
            authorized: false,
            footer: false,
            skipAuthorization: true
        })
```

And i use NodeJS with grunt

Comment: When you put the commas in and it works, if you change them back to dot, do you get that error again? Or does the page work?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20459047/angular-routing-doesnt-work-when-url-is-directly-visited-in-browser-but-works-w